# What does the "Ki" in "KiSelectNextThread" stand for? (Windows Kernel)

Tags: windows, api, kernel

I was reading the book Windows Internals 6th Edition Part 1, Chapter 5, section on "**Thread Selection**" and it states the following:

> "Whenever a logical processor needs to pick the next thread to run, it calls the **KiSelectNextThread** scheduler function."

I tried searching Google and Microsoft and could not find any help. Can someone also tell me what is the significance of the "Ki" and where can I find documentation on this API?

Answer (score 1):

Many of these routines are not documented to create the routine names are created by: prefix + operation + object.
K e/i K is Kernel.
e is external.
i is internal.

Kernel external/internal.